# Can SQL injection be performed through an input like checkbox?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Can SQL injection be performed through an input like checkbox in old Mysql API and how?
Maybe it's a stupid question, but I have no idea if it's possible or not.

Comment: The basic rule for protecting against SQL injections is: Trust *nothing* provided by a user and escape *everything* you put in your database. Use prepared statements whenever possible, they're the most reliable defence.

Comment: When it comes to web secuirty, the only stupid question is the one that was never asked.

Comment: @JonathanEustace That would mean that every question that was ever asked is a stupid question. Kinda illogical.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is when it comes to security ask every question. There are no stupid questions.

Comment: @JonathanEustace ah got it, had a brain lag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100% yes. It all comes down to your server side implementation. When you're sending the data to the server you should be performing input validation. In the case of a checkbox, it's a boolean. You should only be accepting values such as `true` or `false`, `0` or `1`, `checked` etc. If data being sent to the server has a value that doesn't correspond to an expected value it should be tossed away, or even better the IP that sent it should be logged as this is most likely an attempt to hack your server.

With tools like fiddler, CURL or your browser (and your browser's devconsole) you could easily pass in any value to the field that represents that checkbox, thus, input validation is key on the server side.

Comment: People often forget that it takes literally two seconds in Chrome to edit the value of a checkbox and submit a form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The checkbox's value attribute can be edited in Web Inspector or someone could just submit to the URL through code. It just sends along text.